# Codeigniter Editing returned array inside of controller (not view)

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model, controller

CODEIGNITER ISSUE: I can't seem to wrap my head around the array passed back from a model into a controller before sending it to the view.

My controller:

```
function getLatestComp()
{
    $data['latest'] = $this->competitions_model->getLastCompetition();

    echo json_encode($data['latest']);

    $this->load->view('single_competition_view', $data);
}
```

How do I manipulate the returned array?  Here is the returned array:

```
[{"comp_id":"25","song_id1":"178512356","song_id2":"119321744","start_date":"2015-03-23","end_date":"0000-00-00"},{"comp_id":"26","song_id1":"179391155","song_id2":"57429423","start_date":"2015-03-23","end_date":"0000-00-00"},{"comp_id":"27","song_id1":"57429423","song_id2":"52255807","start_date":"2015-03-23","end_date":"0000-00-00"},{"comp_id":"28","song_id1":"57429423","song_id2":"52255807","start_date":"2015-03-23","end_date":"0000-00-00"}]
```

say I just want the second instance's comp_id?

I have tried:

```
$data['latest'][1]->comp_id

$data['latest']->comp_id[1]

$latest[1]->comp_id

$latest[1]['comp_id']
```

How do I get the value I'm looking for?

Comment: can you please add your model? `getLastCompetition` function

Comment: Why are you echoing anything in your controller? You should never do that, and why are you `json_encoding` your return? That just makes it into a json object and you can't handle it in PHP.

Comment: Why are you json_encoding the array you can directly use that array within your view page

Comment: I was just using the json return to see the returned array without erroring on my page.  It really had no use in my app, I wasn't using this in my view.  I know how to use the variable in my view, but I need to call another model after this one returns without returning to my view and bubbling back to the controller etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to access 2nd element of your object.
I think you returned data from your model like this `get()->result()`
if you want to get your 2nd element inside controller it should work

```
$data['latest'][1]->comp_id;//if your php version>=5.4
```

If your php version is lower then use this

```
$second_object=$data['latest'][1];
$second_object->comp_id;
```

similarly if you want get it inside your view use this way

```
$latest[1]->comp_id;//if php version>=5.4
//otherwise
$second_object=$latest[1];
$second_object->comp_id;
```

if you return data as array from your model like this `...get()->result_array()` then you can accesses it easily

```
$data['latest'][1]['comp_id'];//inside your controller
$latest[1]['comp_id'];//inside  your view
```

Hope this you understands it and solves your problem.

Comment: The first is what I needed.  I thought I had tried that already, apparently not...  THANKS!